# Hi folks, In one of my Agent Job is running by every minute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

One of my SQL agent Job is running every minute, the job has failed . I need the job history of past five days.

Is there any way we can get the history details?

I have searched in the log but not able to find the details.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the output of this query when you run in `msdb` database?

Comment: Jo got failed i.e Application Job , they asked us to investigate

Comment: Sorry I meant this query in msdb database `SELECT min(run_date) FROM sysjobhistory`?

Comment: it is showing o/p 20170801

Comment: That means you do not have last 5 days of data and there is no way to recover without restoring backup. See the 2 answers posted.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you have configured the history for the Sql Agent, you may have lost that information.  From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754442) answer:

> The SQL Server Job system limits the total number of job history
>   entries both per job and over the whole system. This information is
>   stored in the MSDB database.
>
> Obviously you won't be able to go back and see information that has
>   been since discarded, but you can change the SQL Server Agent
>   properties and increase the number of entries that will be recorded
>   from now on.
>
> In the SQL Server Agent Properties:

- Select the History page
- Modify the 'Maximum job history log size (rows)' and 'Maximum job
  history rows per job' to suit, or change how historical job data is
  deleted based on its age.

> It won't give you back your history, but it'll help with your future
>   queries!

You might be able to tweak the following query to give you the information you're looking for (if it still exists).  I got the query from [here](http://stevestedman.com/2016/03/tsql-script-display-agent-job-history/).

```
;WITH jobListCTE as
(
SELECT j.name as job_name,
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS run_datetime,
RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), run_duration), 6) AS run_duration,
message
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON h.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE h.step_name = '(Job outcome)'
)
SELECT job_name as [JobStep],
run_datetime as [StartDateTime],
SUBSTRING(run_duration, 1, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(run_duration, 3, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(run_duration, 5, 2) as [Duration],
message
FROM jobListCTE
ORDER BY run_datetime DESC, job_name;
```

Comment: the cript has given today job history

Comment: To add to Scott's answer, if you need more detailed step information, you can also log the output of the step to an output file or table.  Click the Advanced Page on the Step Edit window and enable the appropriate logging option.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a regular msdb backups, you can restore these backups one by one and search for the information you are looking for using, for example, the script presented by Scott Hodgin

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust something here to keep a long period of history. Right click SQL Server Agent - Properties

[image]